# given x by x grid of characters, find word and its location

Tags: python

looking for suggestion on algorithm/script to look for word within the list of list below,
A word can be read :

1. horizontally from left to right
2. vertically from top to bottom
3. diagonally from top left to bottom right

return

```
L = [['N', 'D', 'A', 'O', 'E', 'L', 'D', 'L', 'O', 'G', 'B', 'M', 'N', 'E'],
 ['I', 'T', 'D', 'C', 'M', 'E', 'A', 'I', 'N', 'R', 'U', 'T', 'S', 'L'],
 ['C', 'L', 'U', 'U', 'E', 'I', 'C', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'O', 'L', 'I', 'I'],
 ['K', 'M', 'U', 'I', 'M', 'U', 'I', 'D', 'I', 'R', 'I', 'A', 'L', 'T'],
 ['E', 'U', 'R', 'T', 'U', 'N', 'G', 'S', 'T', 'E', 'N', 'B', 'V', 'H'],
 ['L', 'I', 'L', 'S', 'L', 'T', 'T', 'U', 'L', 'R', 'U', 'O', 'E', 'I'],
 ['C', 'M', 'A', 'T', 'E', 'T', 'I', 'U', 'R', 'D', 'R', 'C', 'R', 'U'],
 ['I', 'D', 'S', 'C', 'A', 'M', 'A', 'G', 'N', 'E', 'S', 'I', 'U', 'M'],
 ['M', 'A', 'M', 'P', 'D', 'M', 'U', 'I', 'N', 'A', 'T', 'I', 'T', 'I'],
 ['P', 'C', 'N', 'P', 'L', 'A', 'T', 'I', 'N', 'U', 'M', 'D', 'L', 'L'],
 ['H', 'Z', 'E', 'M', 'A', 'N', 'G', 'A', 'N', 'E', 'S', 'E', 'I', 'G'],
 ['M', 'G', 'I', 'T', 'I', 'N', 'R', 'U', 'N', 'O', 'R', 'I', 'T', 'C'],
 ['R', 'I', 'A', 'N', 'N', 'A', 'M', 'E', 'R', 'C', 'U', 'R', 'Y', 'N'],
 ['U', 'O', 'T', 'C', 'C', 'R', 'E', 'P', 'P', 'O', 'C', 'E', 'E', 'R']]
```

I am thinking of format like

```
def find_word(filename, word):
    location = find_word_horizontally(grid, word)
    found = False
    if location:
        found = True
        print(word, 'was found horizontally (left to right) at position', location)
    location = find_word_vertically(grid, word)
    if location:
        found = True
        print(word, 'was found vertically (top to bottom) at position', location)
    location = find_word_diagonally(grid, word)
    if location:
        found = True
        print(word, 'was found diagonally (top left to bottom right) at position', location)
    if not found:
        print(word, 'was not found')

def find_word_horizontally(grid, word):

def find_word_vertically(grid, word):

def find_word_diagonally(grid, word):
```

expected output:

```
find_word('word_search_1.txt', 'PLATINUM')
PLATINUM was found horizontally (left to right) at position (10, 4)

find_word('word_search_1.txt', 'LITHIUM')
LITHIUM was found vertically (top to bottom) at position (2, 14)

find_word('word_search_1.txt', 'MISS')
LITHIUM was found vertically (top to bottom) at position (2, 5)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a generator that does what you are looking for using Numpy to manipulate the letter matrix.

```
import numpy as np

def find_word(w, m):
    for r, row in enumerate(m,1):
        s = ''.join(row)
        if w in s:
            yield ('H', r, s.find(w)+1)
    for c, col in enumerate(m.T, 1):
        s = ''.join(col)
        if w in s:
            yield ('V', s.find(w)+1, c)
    for v in range(-max(m.shape), max(m.shape)):
        s = ''.join(m.diagonal(v))
        if w in s:
            p = s.find(w)
            r, c = (abs(v), 0)
            if v > 0:
                r, c = c, r
            r, c = r+p, c+p
            yield ('D', r+1, c+1)
```

You can use the output to populate the print strings.

```
m = np.array(L)
d_dict = {'H': 'horizontally (left to right)', 
          'V': 'horizontally (left to right)', 
          'D': 'diagonally (top left to bottom right)'}

for word in ('PLATINUM', 'LITHIUM', 'MIIS'):
    for ret in find_word(word, m):
        d, x, y = ret
        print(f'{word} was found {d_dict[d]} as postion {x,y}')
```

Printed output:

```
PLATINUM was found horizontally (left to right) as postion (10, 4)
LITHIUM was found horizontally (left to right) as postion (2, 14)
MIIS was found diagonally (top left to bottom right) as postion (2, 5)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, numpy is quite new to me, took me sometime to get it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a DFS to find the word like this:

```
class Find:
  def __init__(self):
    self.dx = [1, 1, 0] #go down, go diag, go right
    self.dy = [0, 1, 1]

  def FindWord(self, grid, word):
    if len(word) == 0:
       return False

    m = len(grid)
    if m == 0:
       return False

    n = len(grid[0])
    if n == 0:
       return False

    for i in range(m):
      for j in range(n):
         for d in range(3): #try all 3 directions
            if self.Helper(grid, word, i, j, 0, m, n, d):
                print("Found word at " + str(i) + "," + str(j))
                return True
    return False

  def Helper(self, grid, word, x, y, k, rows, cols, direction):
    if k == len(word):
       return True

    if grid[x][y] != word[k]:
       return False

    new_x = x + self.dx[direction]
    new_y = y + self.dy[direction]

    return (self.InBound(new_x, new_y, rows, cols) and self.Helper(grid, word, new_x, new_y, k + 1, rows, cols, direction))

  def InBound(self, i, j, rows,cols):
    return (i >= 0 and i < rows and j >= 0 and j < cols)



L = [['N', 'D', 'A', 'O', 'E', 'L', 'D', 'L', 'O', 'G', 'B', 'M', 'N', 'E'],
 ['I', 'T', 'D', 'C', 'M', 'E', 'A', 'I', 'N', 'R', 'U', 'T', 'S', 'L'],
 ['C', 'L', 'U', 'U', 'E', 'I', 'C', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'O', 'L', 'I', 'I'],
 ['K', 'M', 'U', 'I', 'M', 'U', 'I', 'D', 'I', 'R', 'I', 'A', 'L', 'T'],
 ['E', 'U', 'R', 'T', 'U', 'N', 'G', 'S', 'T', 'E', 'N', 'B', 'V', 'H'],
 ['L', 'I', 'L', 'S', 'L', 'T', 'T', 'U', 'L', 'R', 'U', 'O', 'E', 'I'],
 ['C', 'M', 'A', 'T', 'E', 'T', 'I', 'U', 'R', 'D', 'R', 'C', 'R', 'U'],
 ['I', 'D', 'S', 'C', 'A', 'M', 'A', 'G', 'N', 'E', 'S', 'I', 'U', 'M'],
 ['M', 'A', 'M', 'P', 'D', 'M', 'U', 'I', 'N', 'A', 'T', 'I', 'T', 'I'],
 ['P', 'C', 'N', 'P', 'L', 'A', 'T', 'I', 'N', 'U', 'M', 'D', 'L', 'L'],
 ['H', 'Z', 'E', 'M', 'A', 'N', 'G', 'A', 'N', 'E', 'S', 'E', 'I', 'G'],
 ['M', 'G', 'I', 'T', 'I', 'N', 'R', 'U', 'N', 'O', 'R', 'I', 'T', 'C'],
 ['R', 'I', 'A', 'N', 'N', 'A', 'M', 'E', 'R', 'C', 'U', 'R', 'Y', 'N'],
 ['U', 'O', 'T', 'C', 'C', 'R', 'E', 'P', 'P', 'O', 'C', 'E', 'E', 'R']]


inst = Find()
inst.FindWord(L, "TUI")
```

The output in this case will be "Found Word at 1,1"